# Проблема с директорией home в Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hdd

Появилась проблема с определением размера диска, который монтирован на /home в Ubuntu 14. В эту точку монтирован диск размером около 400ГБ. Последние несколько дней при перезагрузке появляется ошибка монтирования /home, система предлагает исправить, через несколько секунд система запускается и работает.... через несколько часов возникает ошибка записи в папку /home, проверяю с помощью анализатора использования диска  (Baobab) (запускаю от sudo), показывает использование диска 100% и размер только 65,9ГБ (это около 16% всего диска)... Хотел что-то удалить в Nautilus - в контекстном меню кнопка удалить над любой папкой/файлом не активна, хотя зашел под рутом...

При попытки удалить из командной строки, пишет `"файловая система доступна только для чтения"`.

При попытки перемонтировать диск командой `fsck.ext4 -f /dev/sdb5` система пытается восстановить диск, 100 раз спрашивает, нужно ли исправить ошибку, но в результате ничего не изменилось...

Подскажите, как исправить.

Comment: Сдается мне, винчестер дохнет, надо менять

Comment: как можно проверить?

Comment: @Alex, `aptitude -y install smartmontools && smartctl --all /dev/sdb`. Выхлопом дополни вопрос.

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How can I check the health of my hard drive?](http://askubuntu.com/q/38566/3712)

Comment: при установке утилиты получил ошибку === Настраивается пакет bind9 (1:9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.10) …
 * Starting domain name service... bind9                                 [fail] 
invoke-rc.d: initscript bind9, action "start" failed.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета bind9 (--configure):
 подпроцесс установлен сценарий post-installation возвратил код ошибки 1
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 bind9
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1) ====

Comment: Копируй файлО в облако, на внешний винт, пока есть что копировать. И не перезагружай комп.

Comment: == VirtualBox или docker вместо реальной системы== это не понял...
по bind9  - возможно там закачались другие обновления, поэтому и вылетила эта ошибка... завтра на работе перегружу сервер, возможно после этого нормально установится пакет...

Comment: @jfs, если винту приходят кранты, то будет глючить ЧТО УГОДНО. Начиная от `nano` и заканчивая ядром. Проги всё-таки лежат в конечном итоге на магнитных дорожках, которые считывает фигня, которая летит над поверхностью блина в долях милиметра, который в свою очередь крутится со скоростью 7200 оборотов в минуту (ну можно и 5400, всё равно дофига). А это в свою очередь контролирует контроллер, который в свою очередь распаян безсвинцовым припоем. И это всё хрен пойми как работает даже не один год. Ты уверен, что в компуктере нечему ломаться - ведь там всё просто и надёжно?

Comment: @jfs, а ещё не надо забывать про глюки чипсета, хреновый кабель sata, на котором иногда пишут `28 AWG`. А если у ОПа блок питания фирмы `3cott` или `linkworld`, то тут вообще непонятно как комп до сих пор включается.

Comment: @Alex: это меня переклинило: я до этого комментировал на вопросе, где человек версию системного питона менял. В контексте падающего винта, VM или docker смысла не имеют. Стёр комментарий, чтобы в заблуждение не вводить.

Comment: @donRumata: см. выше.

Comment: @jfs, ааа, ок, бывает.

Comment: а  gparted чего говрит??? загрузитесь с live и проганиете диск с хомяком.